# Mock Interface function not getting called

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, testify

I'm trying to write Go Unit Test using testify mocking library. I was following this blog http://goinbigdata.com/testing-go-code-with-testify/. I have passed the mocked interface to the newCalculator function but still Random1 of Random interface is getting called instead of Random1 function of struct randomMock.

calculator.go

```
package calculator

type Random interface {
  Random1(limit int) int
}

func newCalculator(rnd Random) Random {
  return calc{
    rnd: rnd,
  }
}

type calc struct {
  rnd Random
}

func (c calc) Random1(limit int) int {
  return limit
}
```

calculator_test.go

```
package calculator

import (
  "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
  "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
  "testing"
)

type randomMock struct {
  mock.Mock
}

func (o randomMock) Random1(limit int) int {
  args := o.Called(limit)
  return args.Int(0)
}

func TestRandom(t *testing.T) {
  rnd := new(randomMock)
  rnd.On("Random1", 100).Return(7)
  calc := newCalculator(rnd)
  assert.Equal(t, 7, calc.Random1(100))
}

Output on running: go test
--- FAIL: TestRandom (0.00s)
calculator_test.go:22:
        Error Trace:    calculator_test.go:22
        Error:          Not equal:
                        expected: 7
                        actual  : 100
        Test:           TestRandom
FAIL
exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it myself. I was missing the call to the struct rnd first.

```
func (c calc) Random1(limit int) int {
  return c.rnd.Random1(limit)
}
```